# Modify properties of an object stored in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java coming from Javascript.

If i have an ArrayList of objects how do I modify the value of a property of the object inside the ArrayList.

I have tried `ArrayList.set(index, value)`, but because I have an object, an error is shown saying `value is int expected com.package.object`

```
arraylist.set(arraylist.get(0).position[1], ???);
```

Comment: What's the type of `arraylist`? (what elements are you storing in it?)  Are you trying to set a new value in position 0 of the ArrayList, or to modify the current value stored in that position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arraylist.get(0).position[1] = newvalue
```

it's that easy.

better is to add null checks(assuming position is an integer array)

```
/**
 * position: where in the arraylist to store. 
 * newvalue: the value to set
 */
 public void setPositionValue(int position, int newvalue) {
    /** check if valid arraylist index **/
    if(position < this.arraylist.size()) {
        MyObject myobject = this.arraylist.get(position);
        /** check if we got something valid back **/
        if(myobject != null) { 
           /** check if array is set and length is valid **/
           if(myobject.position != null && myobject.position.length > 1) {
               myobject.position[1] = newvalue;
           }
        }
    }

}
```

Also, make your arraylists in a specific type.

You now problay have defined:

```
Arraylist arraylist = new ArrayList();
```

Then you have a 'catchall' arraylist, anything could be in there. This is not preferred. You want to know what you're dealing with!

So better to do:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> arraylist = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

by putting the `<MyObject>` there, you are saying to arraylist, ONLY accept and return objects of the instance MyObject or derived from that

Comment: Youre new here. If this answer is the best solution for your problem consider clicking the checkmark to accept the answer